# OpenGL libraries

Tags: c++, opengl

From OpenGL wiki:

"For most libraries you are familiar with, you simply #include a header file, make sure a library is linked into your project or makefile, and it all works. OpenGL doesn't work that way."

I work on Windows 64 and I need OpenGL to use it in C++ application. What library I should use? Does microsoft provide its implementation ( I use MinGW, I do not have MS Visual C++ )?

Comment: That's referring to the fact that OpenGL needs setup that's dependent on the platform you're using. For now, you'd probably be best off using SDL/SFML/GLUT or something the like which makes creating a valid OpenGL context easy. I remember OpenGL setup being a pain on windows (something about having to create a context first before being able to create the context you actually want).

Comment: Try the [unofficial OpenGL Software Development Kit](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html)

Comment: [That very Wiki page goes on to describe what it is you need to do.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Getting_Functions) Along with links to libraries that can simplify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one that comes with your GPU drivers that you have installed on your machine, Microsoft also provides a software layer for OpenGL emulation but it's stuck at the version 1.1 and it's really old and useless.

Answer (score 3):

*What library should I use?*

I recommend using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for easy access to functions of OpenGL 1.2 and higher, [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for mathematics, and [one of these image loading libraries](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries).

*Does microsoft provide its implementation (of OpenGL)?*

Microsoft provides you with the necessary header files and library files to access the OpenGL API. However, in order to use OpenGL functions of version 1.2 and higher, you must use extensions. GLEW does this implicitly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net). It loads needed extensions and core functions.